# How do I use .NET or the Windows API to change the View columns in a particular folder in Windows Explorer? (Windows 7 and Up)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

When browsing a folder in Windows Explorer, I can use the user interface to add additional columns to my view that are typically not there when browsing the folder, such as "File extension" or "Language." In Windows 10, you perform this action by clicking the "View" tab, clicking "Add Columns," clicking "Choose columns...," then selecting the desired columns and clicking "OK."

What I would like to do is perform this action programmatically, ideally adding any column from that list to a chosen directory with hopes of populating that column with metadata. I was looking extensively into methods that could accomplish this, such as the [Column Handler shell extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3747/Explorer-column-handler-shell-extension-in-C), but support for IColumnHandler was dropped after XP and simply won't work.

From there, the only possible option is to use the Property Handler in the Windows API and read the values directly from the registry. However, I am not sure how to go about doing that. I have tried finding some samples online of how to perform this, and it's led me to a bunch of dead ends all around. I understand it must be difficult, but I am sure someone has managed to make it work.

Does anyone has any examples or guidance on how to use the Property Handler in the Windows API to add columns to a View in a Windows Explorer folder? Do I have any other options? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in a shell view, you choose columns by calling IColumnManager::SetColumns with an array of PROPERTYKEY structures.

Assuming you have a Windows Explorer window's IShellBrowser interface, call GetActiveShellView to get the shell view, then query the view object for IColumnManager (a cast in C#).